# Conditional expectation with respect to product of two random variables

Tags: random-variables, conditional-expectation, conditional-probability

If $X$ and $Y$ are independent discrete random variable, how to compute $E(X|XY)$? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

\begin{align*}
\mathbb E[X\mid XY](\omega ')&=\mathbb E[X\mid XY=X(\omega ')Y(\omega ')]\\
&=\sum_{\omega \in \Omega }X(\omega )\mathbb P\{X=X(\omega )\mid XY=X(\omega ')Y(\omega ')\}\\
&=\sum_{\omega \in \Omega }X(\omega  )\frac{\mathbb P\{X=X(\omega ),XY=X(\omega ')Y(\omega ')\}}{\mathbb P\{XY=X(\omega ')Y(\omega ')\}}.
\end{align*}

Without further information, it's not possible to do better.

Comment: I was hopping there is some theorem that can give some more specific answer. I couldn't find it. And it seams that apart from the pure definition of conditional expectation and conditional probability, there is nothing it can be done. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If $P(A)>0$
$$E(X|A)=\frac{E(X1_A)}{P(A)}$$

[Conditional_expectation_with_respect_to_an_event](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_expectation#Conditional_expectation_with_respect_to_an_event)

So 
$$E(X|XY=t)=\frac{E(X1_{\{XY=t\}})}{P(XY=t)}$$

$$=\frac{\sum_{(x,y)} x1_{\{xy=t\}} P(X=x,Y=y)}{P(XY=t)}$$

$$=\frac{\sum_{\{(x,y)| xy=t\}} x P(X=x,Y=y)}{P(XY=t)}$$

$$=\frac{\sum_{\{(x,y)| xy=t\}} x P(X=x)P(Y=y)}{P(XY=t)}$$